# Traversing to a table element from a nested element

Tags: jquery, dom

I have the following bit of code.  I'm trying to locate the nearest table from the btn primary being clicked

```
          <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="pull-right">
            <h3><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-add-ebook-retailer"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_retailer_link">Add Retailer Link</a></h3>
          </div>
          <table class="table table-striped table-opaque">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Actions</th>
              <th>Retailer</th>
              <th>Country</th>
              <th>URL</th>
              <th>ASIN</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <% @title.retailer_links.each do |link|%>
                <% if link.retailer_id == 1 || link.retailer_id == 2 || link.retailer_id == 6  %>
                <tr>
                  <td class="actions"><a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-edit-retailer-link" data-retailer-id="<%=link.id%>"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-fw"></i></a> <a href="" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-delete-retailer-link" data-retailer-id="<%=link.id%>"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i></a></td>
                  <td><%= link.retailer.display_name%></td>
                  <td><%= link.locale%></td>
                  <td><a href="<%= link.product_uri%>" target="_blank"><%= link.product_uri.truncate(153)%></a></td>
                  <td><%= link.asin%></td>
                <%end%>
            <%end%>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```

I'e tried this.

```
       $('#save_new_retailer_link').on('click', function (event) {


        $(this).closest("div").siblings("table").append('<tr><td class="actions"><a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-edit-retailer-link" ' +
        'data-retailer-id="263787"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-fw"></i></a> <a href="" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-delete-retailer-link" ' +
        'data-retailer-id="263787"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i></a></td><td> </td><td></td></tr>');
```

});

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is your definition of "nearest table"?  Do you mean the next table after the button?

Comment: Yes.  The one after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the next table element after the button, you can go up from the button to the containing div and then find the next `<table>` element at that level.

If `this` is the clicked on button element, then you can do this:

```
var t = $(this).closest("div").nextAll("table").eq(0);
```

This goes up the parent chain from the button to the containing div, then gets all the following `table` elements at that level, then gets just the first one (in case there is more than one).

I've long thought that jQuery was missing a function to find the next sibling that matches a particular selector so that's what the `.nextAll("table").eq(0)` does.

Comment: I'm attempting to append a row to this table once I traverse to it.  I'm using t.append but it doesn't seem to work.  Why is this?